# Formula editor: sum character too small

Tags: openoffice.org

For some reason, when using the formula editor the sum character is always too small for me, making it look completely out of place and also ruining the alignment of limits etc.

For example, when trying the topmost example from https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Writer_Guide/Common_problem_areas

```
sum from k = 1 to n a_k
```

The result for me is:
[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqey6.png)

The alignment / character size does not change when deselecting the formula. This is very different from what it should look like and looks at the wiki page linked above.

As can be seen by the little gray box shown when the cursor is on the sum word in the formula editor, the character is too small and stuck in the lower left corner. As an effect the limits are displayed seemingly too far on the right and the upper limit looks very distanced. The size of the sum character also does not fit the following characters.

What could be the reason for this and how could this be fixed? I tried opening a new blank presentation and the problem also persisted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change relative operator size. Try the following:

1. Double click on the formula and Format -> Distance (the option after "Font Size").
2. From the drop down menu "Category" select "Operator"
3. If "Excess size" is not 100% then set it to 100%.

Hope that this will helps.

Comment: Okay, I tried this. This makes the entire sum sign bigger, but it remains stuck at not full size in its box, which means that it is still misaligned to its limits. 
So this helps with the size relative to the following formula, but does not solve the issue with the limits looking completely off.